# When I animate, I get 10 different actions?

Tags: animation, dopesheet

I'm animating a hand animation, but the dope sheet has ended up with around 10 different actions and I have no idea how to merge them:

[image]

Comment: Are you asking why you are ending up with so many actions or are you asking how to merge them?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to merge (append) the actions into a single action you could select the keyframes in the action editor to copy and paste <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> them. Both are also accesible from the *Key-Menu*:

[image]

In case you want to cross-fade them you would need to use the NLA-Editor and arrange the actions on its timeline.

[image]

Comment: I will try that ;P

Comment: mmm i have a mac and nothing seems to be working

Comment: maybe i should use different shortcuts?

Comment: The mac uses Cmd-C to copy instead of Ctrl-C same as copy in any other app. Copy and Paste are also available in the Key menu.

Comment: wait key menu??

Comment: @Knuckles209cp Yes change the Dopesheet to Action-Editor than you can use the Key-Menu the first menu items at the top are Copy/Paste and should show their OS-specific shortcuts. I added another screenshot to my answer.

Comment: wow thanks , i will try that out and see how everything goes ! Appreciate it :)